# Is "an upper bound of A, denoted by upper(A), can be derived as follows:" a normal English expression?

Tags: grammar, expressions, nouns

Recently, I'm writing an English paper. In a section, I want to define an upper bound of A as upper(A). To avoid duplication, I wan to combine two sentences:

> When pre-contingency security constraints are satisfied, an upper
>   bound of A can be derived as follows:
>
> ...
>
> where upper(A) is the an upper bound of A when pre-contingency
>   security constraints are satisfied.

I rewrite the sentence as:

> When pre-contingency security constraints are satisfied, an upper bound of A, denoted by upper(A), can be derived by combining (26) and (29):

or

> When pre-contingency security constraints are satisfied, an upper
>   bound of A, upper(A), can be derived by combining (26) and (29):

However, I feel a bit strange when reading it. So can you help me with improving this expression?
Thanks!

Besides, how do you think this sentence:

> When pre-contingency security constraints (34)-(35) and post-contingency security constraints (39) are satisfied, two upper bounds of A, denoted by upper1(A) and upper2(A), can be derived to identify if constraint (38) is inactive:

Comment: If you treat “upper(A)” as filling the role of a noun or as shorthand for the noun phrase it expands to, the sentence is grammatical.

Comment: @Wang **Why** did it (or you) "feel a bit strange"? It's exactly the same as a sentence like "A police force, denoted by *MyPD*, can be created by..." (I don't really like your second alternative: that's too condensed.)

Comment: Maybe the reason is that "," causes some breaks when I read it or the sentence "when ..." makes this expression different from this example. It's hard to say since I'm from China. In fact, if the native speakers think this expression is OK, I will also accpet it.